# Laravel 5.2 not broadcasting events

Tags: events, laravel-5, broadcast, pusher

I've tried to broadcast event with pusher. But after a long hours of debugging I am still without a working solution.

Pusher works great, it's getting events from the debug console. Laravel is also firing the event. I also set up the queue and broadcasting configuration, but I noticed that my queue listener never getting any response.

This is my event listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\SomeEvent;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class EventListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  SomeEvent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(SomeEvent $event)
    {
        //dd($event);
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('event', function () {
    event(new App\Events\SomeEvent());
    return "event fired";
});
```

Event file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class SomeEvent extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $data;
    public $x = 1111;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = array(
            'power'=> '10'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['test_channel'];
    }

}
```

Edit:
i reinstalled laravel and now the queue seems to respond and create row in the job table. but the pusher still dont recive any events from laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Your `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider` needs to be made aware of the events and listeners.

```
protected $listen = [
    App\Events\SomeEvent::class => [
        App\Listeners\SomeListener::class,
    ],
];
```

These can be automatically populated by running `php artisan event:generate`.